# Intersection of fractional Sobolev spaces

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $H^0 (\mathbb{R}^N) := L^2 (\mathbb{R}^N)$. Suppose that $v \in \bigcap_{s \in [0,1)} H^s (\mathbb{R}^N) \supseteq H^1 (\mathbb{R}^N)$ and additionaly, $v \in H^1_{loc} (\mathbb{R}^N)$. Can one show that $v \in H^1 (\mathbb{R}^N)$? If not, what is the example of such function?

As far as I can see, it is clear that $v \in L^2 (\mathbb{R}^N)$ and it has a weak derivative $\nabla v \in L^2_{loc} (\mathbb{R}^N)$. Is true that $\nabla v \in L^2 (\mathbb{R}^N)$?

Comment: I would say that the answer is no. But I haven't come out with an explicit example.